# Flutter Application Freezing when download large file

Tags: flutter, encryption, flutter-test

Now I made a script that encrypts my videos and downloads them to the application storage, But now when I try to download a small file size I don't face any issues, but when I try to download a large file my application is stuck at 99% and take about 2 minutes to save the file to application storage.

`[![99% of file downloading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3UUu.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3UUu.jpg)

My Code

`

`````
final String url = streamInfo.url.toString();
final dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
String appDocPath = dir.path;
print("Downloading...");
var resp = await dio.get(url,
    options: Options(
      responseType: ResponseType.bytes,
      followRedirects: false,
    ),
    onReceiveProgress: (recivedBytes, totalBytes) {
      setState(() {
        progress = recivedBytes / totalBytes;
      });
    },
);
print(resp.data);

var encResult = _encryptData(resp.data);


_writeData(encResult, appDocPath + '/${widget.lessoneName.toString()}.aes');
print("File downloaded successfully");`
```

```
_encryptData(str){
  final encrypted = MyEncrypt.myEncrypt.encryptBytes(str,iv:MyEncrypt.myIv);
  return encrypted.bytes;
}
Future<String> _writeData(str,path) async{
  print("Writting data");
  File f = File(path);
  print(f);
  await f.writeAsBytes(str);
  return f.absolute.toString();
}
````


```
class MyEncrypt{
  static final myKey = esc.Key.fromUtf8('TechWithVPTechWithVPTechWithVP12');
  static final myIv = esc.IV.fromUtf8('VivekPanacha1122');
  static final myEncrypt = esc.Encrypter(esc.AES(myKey));
}
```
`````

Comment: Howe big is the large file?

Comment: You are doing 3 thing in sequence .. 1) Download data, 2) Encrypt data & 3) Write encrypted data to file .. Your progress indicator only shows step 1 .. and thus freezes during step 2 and 3.

Comment: @EbbeM.Pedersen so how can I fix this

Comment: @GrahamD about 200mb

Comment: Ebbe has given you the reason for the freeze. You are downloading and processing large amounts of data. It will take time, there is no way around that. You need to manage your UX. Look at what can be done in the background whilst keeping the user happy. Also, where I come from , mobile data is expensive and a user may not be happy using 200mb of it. You need to consider that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you have found a solution to this issue
anyway I will write the correct solution for others who are facing such issues

you have to use isolate to reading data as bytes so that it has not affected on UI

with isolate, you send expensive operations to the background which means you made a new thread so that you catch the result after it done
by the way, remember your function (in this case read data as bytes) should be high-level method

here is the sample code

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:isolate';

import 'package:dio/dio.dart' as dio;
import 'package:encrypt/encrypt.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';


class DownloadFileModel {
  final SendPort sendPort;
  final dio.Response<dynamic> response;
  final String savePath;

  DownloadVideoModel({
    required this.response,
    required this.sendPort,
    required this.savePath,
  });
}

class DownloadFile {
  dio.Dio request = dio.Dio();
  void downloadNewFile(String url) async {
    final dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String appDocPath = dir.path;
    var resp = await request.get(
      url,
      options: dio.Options(
        responseType: dio.ResponseType.bytes,
        followRedirects: false,
      ),
      onReceiveProgress: (receivedBytes, totalBytes) {
        print(receivedBytes / totalBytes);
      },
    );
    ReceivePort port = ReceivePort();
    Isolate.spawn(
      whenDownloadCompleted,
      DownloadFileModel(
          response: resp, sendPort: port.sendPort, savePath: appDocPath),
    );
    port.listen((encryptedFilePath) {
      print(encryptedFilePath);
      port.close();
    });
  }
}

class MyEncrypt {
  static final myKey = Key.fromUtf8('TechWithVPTechWithVPTechWithVP12');
  static final myIv = IV.fromUtf8('VivekPanacha1122');
  static final myEncrypt = Encrypter(AES(myKey));
}

void whenDownloadCompleted(DownloadVideoModel model) async {
  SendPort sendPort = model.sendPort;
  var encryptResult =
      MyEncrypt.myEncrypt.encryptBytes(iv: MyEncrypt.myIv, model.response.data);
  File encryptedFile = File("${model.savePath}/myFile.aes");
  encryptedFile.writeAsBytes(encryptResult.bytes);
  sendPort.send(encryptedFile.absolute.path);
}
```

For more info head over to flutter official document site

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-isolate/Isolate-class.html